# SQL case 0 then NULL

Tags: sql, case

I want to get `NULL` when the number in my table is 0. How can I achieve this using SQL? I tried

```
SELECT ID, 
       Firstname, 
       Lastname, 
       CASE Number 
         WHEN 0 THEN NULL 
       END
  FROM tPerson
```

But this results in an error:

> At least one of the result expressions in a CASE specification must be
> an expression other than the NULL constant.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As others have mentioned you forgot to tell your CASE statement to return the number in case the number is not null.

However in SQL Server you can use NULLIF, which I consider more readable:

```
select 
  id, 
  firstname, 
  lastname, 
  nullif(number, 0) as number
from tperson;
```

If you want to stick to standard SQL then stay with CASE:

```
case when number = 0 then null else number end as number
```

Comment: isn't the nullif(number,0) doing the opposite of what is requested ? ie replacing null by 0 instead of 0 by null

Comment: @sdementen: No. It replaces a 0 by null as requested. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @sdementen you're thinking of IsNull

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ID, Firstname, Lastname,
 CASE WHEN Number!=0 THEN Number END 
FROM tPerson
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you need `ELSE`:

```
SELECT 
  ID, Firstname, Lastname CASE Number WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE Number END
FROM tPerson
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use IIF() with sql server 2012 and above

```
SELECT ID, 
       Firstname, 
       Lastname, 
       IIF(Number = 0, NULL, Number) as Number 
       END
FROM tPerson
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT ID, Firstname, 
   Lastname, 
   CASE Number WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE Number END 
FROM tPerson
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can also use `if`:

```
select if(number = 0, null, number) ...
```

Comment: 'If' cannot be used within select

Comment: In SQL-Server? I can not be used

Comment: @Lali Who says this is SQL-Server? Certainly not the OP.

Comment: I saw a tag with sql-server